# sceptics.se should redirect to skeptics.se

Tags: feature-request

The URL [`http://sceptics.stackexchange.com`](http://sceptics.stackexchange.com) (currently dead) should redirect to the page http://skeptics.stackexchange.com; all `/path` URLs should likewise redirect. (*Sceptics* is the Commonwealth spelling and *skeptics* the American.)

Comment: Good suggestion.  I agree with you.

Comment: Very good suggestion. On a different point, though, I'm british but still prefer and use the "skeptics" spelling whenever I se the word. Not all "american" spellings are bad.

Comment: @matt_black Heresy

Comment: Why does the the header of the question say: "**sceptics.se should redirect to skeptics.se**" when the body talks about **sceptics.stackexchange.com** redirecting to **skeptics.stackexchange.com**?

Comment: In the context of the skeptics movement, “skeptics” is the predominant British spelling, too (see e.g. “Skeptics in the Pub”). I’m still in favour of a redirect though.

Comment: @johanges: because one is the "nickname" of the site and the other is the actuall URL?

Comment: Note that http://maths.stackexchange.com redirects to http://math.stackexchange.com, so there is precedent for such a move.

Comment: 0 answers in 5 years for a simple and obvious request.